# Why i can't make absolute div height 100%

Tags: html, css

I have problem, I have one fixed container, inside them I have absolute div, I want to set `.absolute` div `height:100%;` to be full height of container div(500px).
Here is what I tried to solve my problem, this need because I want to create mobile menu with toggle container, and its important for me to be height **`100%`** of mobile phone screen.

https://jsfiddle.net/d1bh9ncs/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="fixed">
    <div class="absolute">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  background-color:#ddd;
}
.fixed{
  position:fixed; 
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
  top:8px;
  left:8px;
  right:15px;
}
.absolute{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:green;
  top:51px;
  left:0px;
}
```

Comment: Your .fixed div has a height of 50px, and your .absolute div's 100% is relative to .fixed, so he also has 50px height.

Comment: you can use `height:100vh;` for the `.absolute`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The parent div `.fixed` is absolutely positioned and has a height 50px. So applying `height: 100%`on it's child will inherit the relative height(i.e 50px).

Use `height: 100vh;` on `.absolute`. I have used calculated height `height: calc(100vh - 51px)` to avoid scrollbar due to `top: 51px`.

**Note**: `vh` is 1/100th of the height of the viewport(visible webpage height).

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/d1bh9ncs/5/)**

```
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  height: calc(100vh - 51px);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  top: 51px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: that really works. :) tried to play with `position: relative` before.
also, to make full width `left: 0; right: 0;`

Answer (score 3):

you are using Fixed div as an Parent div of Absolute div, Absolute div can have 100% of Fixed div it can't extend to its parent's height if you add height value in Percentage.If you want it to extend as parent height you must have to add height in px (pixels)

```
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  background-color:#ddd;
}
.fixed{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height: 101px;
  background-color:red;
  top:8px;
  left:8px;
  right:15px;
}
.absolute{
  position:absolute;
  height: 117px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:green;
  top: 0px !important;
  left:0px;
  z-index: 99999999;
  top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to give height in vh. Put `.absolute` `height = 100vh`

```
 .absolute
 {
 position:absolute;
 height:100vh;
 width:100%;
 background-color:green;
 top:51px;
 left:0px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bj9wcdLs/

Comment: You should explain the difference between vh/vw and %

Comment: but the OP want "full height of container div(500px)"

Comment: `vh` stands for `viewport-height` which is a `css3 unit` (not good browser support) and is related (as the term says) to the viewport. Percentages, from the other side, are related to their parents... probably could be a good thing to have a look here: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/7-css-units-you-might-not-know-about--cms-22573

Answer (score 2):

A more modern way of doing this is to use vh and vw (view height and width). Which rather than being a percentage of its parent (like %) is a percentage of the full page.

In the example below I've done some calc's to help it work out what sizes we really want things.

```js
example = function() {
  var abSel = document.querySelector(".absolute");
  abSel.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100vw - 16px);
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: calc(100vh - 59px);
  width: calc(100vw - 16px);
  background-color: green;
  top: 50px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fixed">
    <button onclick="example()">Example</button>
    <div class="absolute hidden"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just like sticksu said.

Change your code

```
.fixed{
   position:fixed; 
   width:100%;
   height:100%; //must be 100%
   background-color:red;
   top:8px;
   left:8px;
   right:15px;
}
```

Comment: Changing the height of `.fixed` to 100% will make it cover the entire view port (i.e no other content's will be visible)